# Конвертировать рекурсивный объект с двумя типами дочерних к типу с одним

Tags: reactjs, typescript

С сервера приходит json, в котором есть два варианта дочерних элементов

1. `Folder(title : string, id: string, childfolders?: Folder[], childTemps?: Template[], parentFolderId?: string)` (ключевой и всегда корневой)
2. `Template(id: string, title: string, value: string, folderId: string, isDeleted: boolean)`

Надо конвертировать в  `TreeData(id: string, title: string, children: TreeData)` (P.S. могут быть еще параметры, что заполняются вручную)

Как можно решить такую задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
interface Template {
    id: string,
    title: string,
    value: string,
    folderId: string,
    isDeleted: boolean
}

interface Folder {
    id: string,
    title: string,
    childfolders?: Folder[],
    childTemps?: Template[],
    parentFolderId?: string
}

interface TreeData {
    id: string,
    title: string,
    children: TreeData | undefined
}

type $convert = (f: Folder) => TreeData

const convert: $convert = f => {
    let res: TreeData, children: TreeData['children']
    const { id, title, childfolders } = f
    if (undefined !== childfolders) {
        // FIXME: childfolders[0]
        children = convert(childfolders[0])
    }
    res = {
        id,
        title,
        children,
    }
    return res
}
```

Comment: уточняйте пж в вопросе, Типы вам нужны или Код. во втором варианте рекомендую обращаться в [tag:javascript] там выше вероятность того, что вам помогут

Comment: `$convert` - это какое-то соглашение об именах типов функций в `Typescript`?

Comment: это интерфейс, описание типа ф-ии. вставьте код [в песочницу](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#)

Comment: этот ответ можно разделить на две части 1) типы 2) сама реализация ф-ии конвертации вложенных элементов